# Openrefine - use API to retrieve a column from a loaded project

Tags: api, openrefine

I have an active OpenRefine project running where data cleaning is incrementally being done by other team members. I want to extract (read-only) all values in one column, run computations on it in either javascript or python, and display stats on a team dashboard where we have other things being monitored too. For this I need to use the [OpenRefine API](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/OpenRefine-API).

What would be the query needed for retrieving data from one column (example: "dataclean")?

There is this in the documentation:

```
Export rows
Command: POST /command/core/export-rows

'project' : project id
'engine' : JSON string... (e.g. '{"facets":[],"mode":"row-based"}')
'format' : format... (e.g 'tsv', 'csv')
```

Can I pass a `"mode" : "column-based" instead of "row-based" ? What else do I need to specify?

Comment: lol, i had assumed stackoverflow folks will say this is a usage related question not a programming related one so go post it on superuser ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented parameter `options` that will do the trick for you. Just call with `options : {"name":"Column+A"}` (if the column you want is called "Column A"). You can specify a lot more things using this parameter. In OpenRefine, just go to "Export" -> "Custom tabular exporter..." and select the options you want. Then go on the "Option Code" tab, select the JSON and paste it in your query (the format option is ignored in this part, as it is specified using the dedicated parameter).

Comment: sounds good! I'll give this a shot in a couple days time and get back.